# Parse HTML to get specific tags in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, string-parsing

I'm trying to parse an HTML source with Python. I'm using `BeautifulSoup` for the purpose. What I need to get is to get all `td` tags with ids in the form of `nameX` format, where X starts from 1. So they are `name1, name2, ...` as many as we have.

How can I achieve this? My simple code using regex doesn't work.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
resp=soup.find_all("td",{"id":'name*'})
```

Error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use lambda + startswith

```
soup.find_all('td', id=lambda x: x and x.startswith('name'))
```

or regex

```
 soup.find_all('td', id=re.compile('^name'))
```